# Error mapping types while mapping with AutoMapper in C# & .NET

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

In my C# project, I use AutoMapper to map from one type (`CommonInstanceDTOMap`) to another (`CommonInstanceDTO`).

When code is executed it throws exception (below).

> Error trace
> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
> CommonInstanceDTOMap -> CommonInstanceDTO
> Cube.Mapper.Entities.CommonInstanceDTOMap -> Ild_Music.Core.Instances.DTO.CommonInstanceDTO
>
> Type Map configuration:
> CommonInstanceDTOMap -> CommonInstanceDTO
> Cube.Mapper.Entities.CommonInstanceDTOMap -> Ild_Music.Core.Instances.DTO.CommonInstanceDTO
>
> Destination Member:
> Void .ctor(System.Guid, System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[System.Char], System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[System.Byte], Ild_Music.Core.Instances.EntityTag), parameter name

There are both types and Profile stuff below.

```cs
//source type
public record CommonInstanceDTOMap : IMappable
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Avatar { get; set; }
    public EntityTag Tag { get; set; } //enum type
}

//destination type
public struct CommonInstanceDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public ReadOnlyMemory<char> Name { get; }
    public ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Avatar { get; }
    public EntityTag Tag { get; }

    public CommonInstanceDTO(Guid id,
                             ReadOnlyMemory<char> name,
                             ReadOnlyMemory<byte> avatar,
                             EntityTag tag)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Avatar = avatar;
        Tag = tag;
    }
}

// Map profile stuff
public sealed class MapProfile : Profile
{
     //...
     CreateMap<CommonInstanceDTOMap, CommonInstanceDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Guid(src.ID)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name.AsMemory()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Avatar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>src.Avatar.AsMemory()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Tag, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Tag));
    //...
}
```

I tried map with above code, however it throws exception (presented above). Although, everything looking good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper does not know how to convert a `string` to a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` instance. This means that it doesn't know how to call the constructor for `CommonInstanceDTO`, specially what to do with the `name` argument. This parameter is also mentioned in the exception message:

```
Destination Member:
Void .ctor(System.Guid, ..., ..., ...), parameter name
                                                  ^^^^
```

It does know how to convert a `string` (`CommonInstanceDTOMap.ID`) to a `Guid` (`CommonInstanceDTO.ID`), because there is such a constructor [`new Guid(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-guid-ctor(system-string)). It also knows how to convert an array (`CommonInstanceDTOMap.Avatar`) to a `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` (`CommonInstanceDTO.Avatar`), since there is such a constructor [`new ReadOnlyMemory<T>(T[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-readonlymemory-1-ctor(-0())) as well. But since it doesn't know how to convert a `string` to a `ReadOnlyMemory<char>` instance, it fails.

You can specify how to fill the `name` parameter for the constructor with the
[`ForCtorParam()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html) configuration. Specify the constructor parameter name and the value to use in your mapping like this:

```
.ForCtorParam("name", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name.AsMemory()))
```

This way all the four constructor parameters can be filled and AutoMapper is able to create the instance.

Comment: Perhaps a map fits better, it seems like a generic conversion.